# Как правильно расставлять теги <form></form>

Tags: html, вёрстка, form, теги

Мне хочется понять, как правильно расставлять теги `form`. Имеет ли значение, как оформить исходный текст программы - вносить ввод текста, пароля, текстовые области, переключатели и флажки в отдельные теги `form` или писать их все в одном теге? Меняется ли как-то результат выполнения кода (т.е. есть ли вообще какая-то разница)? Конкретно в этой программе, каждый ввод текста, пароля, переключатели и флажки можно разнести в отдельные теги `form`. Измениться ли что-то от этого?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Пример форм</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="">
    <p>Введите имя пользователя:
      <input type="text" name="username" size="20" />
    </p>
    <p>Введите пароль:
      <input type="password" name="pass" size="20" maxlength="8" />
    </p>
    <p>Теперь, пожалуйста, выберите свой любимый язык программирования из данных ниже:</p>
    <input type="radio" name="PL" value="C++" checked="checked" /> C++ <br />
    <input type="radio" name="PL" value="C#" /> C# <br />
    <input type="radio" name="PL" value="Java" /> Java <br />
    <input type="radio" name="PL" value="C"> C <br />
    <p>Выберите, пожалуйста любимую(-ые) среду(среды) разработки.</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="IDE" value="Visual Studio 2017" checked="checked" /> Visual Studio 2017 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="IDE" value="Visual Studio 2015" /> Visual Studio 2015 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="IDE" value="Eclipse" /> Eclipse IDE <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="IDE" value="Notepad++" /> Notepad++ <br />
  </form>
  <form action="">
    <p>Теперь, пожалуйста, оставьте свой отзыв о нашем сайте.</p>
    <textarea cols="30" rows="4">Мой отзыв...</textarea>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А кто будет `label` использовать:?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда нажимаете submit в форме, то отправляются данные только той формы, которой принадлежит этот submit. В вашем случае, если у вас формы работают по-умолчанию как задумано и не обрабатываются js, то за раз можно отправить только либо результаты теста, либо отзыв. Если хотите сразу отправить всё, то нужно создать одну форму.

Comment: То есть в моём случае нужно нажимать два раза на submit. 1-ый - чтобы отправить результаты теста и 2-ой - чтобы отправить комментарий? А чтобы всё отправилось разом, нужно поместить всё это дело в один тег form верно? Я правильно Вас понял?

Comment: вы не сможете нажать два раза на submit, потому что после первого нажатия вы сразу будете перенаправлены на страницу обработчика которая указывается <form action="ВОТ_ТУТ">. Да, вам нужно поместить всё в один тег <form>

Comment: я понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Всё Вам доходчиво объяснили выше. Но могу ещё добавить, что тег "p" в форме - можно заменить на "label". Это больше подходит к правильной вёрстке формы.